# Break apart giant global-style, retaining access to the theme context

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I haven't figured out a clean way to break apart a giant global-style into smaller files that I could, ideally, compose into a single global-style.

It's easy enough to do when you're just interpolating, but the need/want is to retain access to the `theme` context of the global-style such that colors can be applied dynamically.

Is this possible?

Example

```
import css from 'styled-components'
export const thirdp_pace = css`
.pace .pace-progress {
    background: ${({ theme }) =>theme.primary};
    height: 4px;
}
`


import { createGlobalStyle } from 'styled-components';
export const GlobalStyles = createGlobalStyle` 
:focus {
    outline: none !important;
}

${thirdp_pace}
`
```

This is sorta' the idea I'd love to get to, but it doesn't work because `thirdp_pace` doesn't have access to `theme`. And I understand why, I use it only as an example. The goal is to break apart a giant global-style into smaller, bite-sized ones.

Ideally, we'd migrate a lot of the styling info to their dedicated individual components, but that's a much larger task unfortunately.

Comment: How about setting up a static object as your theme which you then export / import, instead of passing it through context as a prop? What's the reason for it being set in the store anyway?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow your question (I'm not sure what store you're referring to). The `theme` object is exposed in the scope of the `createGlobalStyle`, and is one of several objects that are essentially just color mappings that can be applied on the fly, so I can't necessarily just pick the one theme object.

Comment: Have a look at: https://codesandbox.io/s/styled-components-theme-3x6o0 - I included not only colours, but all possible variables you would need to keep consistency within your app. Made based upon material-ui: https://material-ui.com/customization/default-theme/#default-theme

Comment: You can then break your theme outside on a different file and have it exported / imported where you need it - I personally like to keep all global styles in one file though as I find it a bit more organised, but that's just a personal preference really

Comment: What you're describing / showing here is pretty much what I'm doing. My question is asking about breaking pieces of the globalStyle out into separate objects to be included, ensuring access to the theme object is retained. See the example I've provided. Am I missing this idea in your codesandbox link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: Don't use `css` - just return the CSS string you want and call the function

```
export function thirdp_pace(theme) {
    return `
        .pace .pace-progress {
            background: ${theme.primary};
            height: 4px;
        }
    `
}
```

Then

```
import {thirdp_pace} from './styled-components/thirdparty-overrides/pace'
export const GlobalStyles = createGlobalStyle` 

${
    ({theme}) => thirdp_pace(theme)
}
`
```